# Android OpenGL Effectfactory, how to apply multiple effects?

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es

I want to build a photo editor app, and found
  [1]: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/HelloEffects "HelloEffect".

Then I am trying to apply different effects based on current effect already applied. But in the example, the previous effect will be canceled when new effect gets applied. Currently I have to create multiple textures and hold each effect in one texture. I think this is a wrong way to do it, right? Any suggestions? I also want to support undo functions.

Comment: have you got solution to this question?